# Why is $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^i1_{\{\:X_i\:=\:Y_j\:\}}f(Y_j)$ an equivalent representation for the usual Metropolis-Hastings estimator?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, unbiased-estimator, estimators, metropolis-hastings, ergodic

At the beginning of section 2 of the paper [A Vanilla Rao-Blackwellization of Metropolis-Hastings Algorithms](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1291388375), the usual Metorpolis-Hastings estimator of $\int f$ given by the ergodic average $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)$ may equivalently be written as $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^i1_{\left\{\:X_i\:=\:Y_j\:\right\}}f(Y_j)$, where $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is the chain generated by the algorithm, $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the corresponding sequence of proposals and $Y_0:=X_0$.

However, while the idea behind this equivalent representation is clear to me, I don't understand why it holds. Couldn't it be the case that, for a particular outcome $\omega$, $X_i(\omega)=Y_j(\omega)=Y_k(\omega)$ and hence $f(Y_j(\omega))$ is mistakenly counted (at least) twice compared to the ergodic mean?

---

**EDIT**: Let's try to figure out if we can prove $$\operatorname P[\exists 1\le i<j\le k:Y_{n_i}=Y_{n_j}]=0\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }1\le n_1<\cdots<n_k\tag1$$ as suggested in [Taylor's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/434728/222528). It would be sufficient to show that, given $1\le m<n$, $$\operatorname P\left[Y_m=Y_n\right]=0\tag2.$$ In order for this to make sense, we technically need to assume that $\Delta:=\left\{(x,x):x\in E\right\}\in\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$, where $(E,\mathcal E)$ denotes the state space. We know that $$Z_k:=(X_{k-1},Y_k)\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain with transition kernel $$\kappa_{\text{aug}}((x,y),A\times B):=(1-\alpha(x,y))\delta_x(A)Q(x,B)+\delta_y(A)\alpha(x,y)Q(y,B)$$ for $x,y\in E$ and $A,B\in\mathcal E$, where $\alpha$ denotes the acceptance function of the algorithm.. Thus, $$(Z_m,Z_n)\sim\mathcal L(Z_m)\otimes\kappa_{\text{aug}}\tag3$$ and $$\mathcal L(Z_m)\sim\mathcal L(X_{m-1})\otimes Q\tag4,$$ where $Q$ denotes the proposal kernel. Assume $Q$ and the target distribution $\mu$ have a density $q$ and $p$ with respect to a common reference measure $\lambda$. For simplicity, let's focus on the case $n-m=1$. Then, \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\operatorname P\left[Y_{n-1}=Y_n\right]=\operatorname P\left[(Y_{n-1},Y_n)\in\Delta\right]\\&\;\;\;\;=\operatorname P\left[X_{m-1}\in{\rm d}x_1\right]\int Q(x_1,{\rm d}y_1)\int\kappa_{\text{aug}}((x_1,y_1),{\rm d}(x_2,y_2))1_\Delta((y_1,y_2))\end{split}\tag5\end{equation} and \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\int\kappa_{\text{aug}}((x_1,y_1),{\rm d}(x_2,y_2))1_\Delta((y_1,y_2))\\&\;\;\;\;=(1-\alpha(x_1,y_1))\int Q(x_1,{\rm d}y_2)1_\Delta((y_1,y_2))+\alpha(x_1,y_1)\int Q(y_1,{\rm d}y_2)1_\Delta((y_1,y_2))\end{split}\tag6\end{equation} for all $x_1,y_1\in E$.

> How can we show that $(5)$ (or maybe already $(6)$) vanishes?

Comment: the time index thing is confusing me here still. I'll need to agree with that before I agree with how you've written down $\kappa_{\text{aug}}$. I think it might even be more than that though-- when you write $Q(y,B)$, you are saying that the proposal is being generated from previous proposal (which isn't the case for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm).

Comment: Why would it ever be the case that two proposals (from a continuous family of distributions) would be equal? I have a hard time understanding why you would even question this to begin with.

Comment: @Taylor $\kappa_{\text{aug}}$ is the transition kernel of the joint chain. See, for example, section 3.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07174.pdf. ($Q$ is called $P$ therein.)

Comment: @hejseb Intuitively, it should not be possible, but I'm asking how this can be proved formally.

Comment: Indeed we needed to assume that the $Y_i$'s are absolutely continuous. Otherwise double counting could occur.

Comment: @Xi'an What do you mean by "absolutely continuous" here? That their distribution has a density with respect to a reference measure? Should still be not enough (when the reference measure is the counting measure on a discrete space, for example).

Comment: Yes, I mean wrt Lebesgue measure. Or any measure without an atom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, it is sufficient to show that, with probability $1$,  all proposed points $Y_t$ are distinct. Note that the fact that the $X_t$ come from a Markov chain is inessential to showing that the $Y_t$ are distinct.

More precisely, assume that we are working in $\mathbf R^d$, and that the proposal kernel has a density (e.g. a Gaussian random walk proposal). It is then simpler to show the following:

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ be arbitrary points in $\mathbf R^d$. For $i = 1, \ldots, N$, independently draw $Y_i \sim q ( X_i \to Y_i ) $. Then, with probability $1$, $Y_1, \ldots, Y_N$ are all distinct.

The argument of @Taylor then works here: the probability that $Y_i = Y_j$ for *any* pair $(i, j)$ is $0$, since the proposals have a density, and then by a union bound, one deduces that all of the $Y_i$ are distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The proposals are coming from a density, so they should all be different with probability one.

It might make it clearer if you write out a sample path from the algorithm. Think of the chain on the extended space 
$$
(X_t, Y_t) | (X_{t-1}, Y_{t-1}) \sim q(y_t \mid x_{t-1}) p(x_t \mid y_t, x_{t-1})
$$
where $p(x_t \mid y_t, x_{t-1})$ is the binary distribution on the support $\{x_{t-1}, y_t\}$. Say we started the chain at $1.2$ (or written in this way, it would be $(1.2,1.2)$):

```
--------------------------------
Xi      | 1.2 | 5.0| 5.0 | 7.3
--------------------------------
Yj      | 1.2 | 5.0| 6.2 | 7.3
--------------------------------
 action | NA  | Ac | Fa  | Ac
--------------------------------
```

So the first proposal you accept, the second you reject, and then the third you accept. Notice that the inner sum goes from $0$ to $i$. This counts the preceding proposal in the case of a rejection, and it counts the contemporaneous accepted proposal in the case of an acceptance. In either event, you won't double-count anything because $q(y_t | x_{t-1})$ doesn't have any mass on anywhere.

### Edit:

I'm going to suppose $j < i$ to keep more in line with the notation above.

\begin{align*}
P[\exists 1\le j < i\le k:Y_{n_i}=Y_{n_j}] &\le \sum_{1\le j< i\le k} P[Y_{n_i} =  Y_{n_j}] 
\end{align*}

Each summand is an integral over a set of measure $0$. If $n_i$ and $n_j$ are next to each other, for instance, the measure is $\mu_{n_j} \otimes Q$ which has mass on a horizontal slab, but if you integrate over a diagonal sliver, you should be good. Note that $\mu_{n_j}$ is just the marginal distribution, which may or may not be the stationary distribution, but yes, it does have mass on the starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some problems to follow your explanations. First of all, I guess our indices are off by $1$: Given $X_{n-1}$, I sample $Y_n$ from $Q(X_n,\;\cdot\;)$. Now I guess you're assuming the chain is stationary. Then $X_n\sim\mu$ and $Z_n:=(X_{n-1},Y_n)\sim\mu\otimes Q$. Now I don't see how you obtain your formula for the condition distribution. We should have $(Z_n,Z_{n+1})\sim\mathcal L(Z_n)\otimes\kappa$, where $\kappa((x,y),A\times B)=(1-\alpha(x,y))\delta_x(A)Q(x,B)+\delta_y(A)\alpha(x,y)Q(y,B)$. So, $\text P[Z_{n+1}\in A\times B\mid Z_n]=\kappa(Z_n,A\times B)$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is denoting the acceptance function of the algorithm. (b) In order to show that all proposals are different with probability $1$, we would need to show that for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and $n_1<\cdots<n_k$, $$\operatorname P[\exists 1\le i<j\le k:Y_{n_i}=Y_{n_j}]=0.$$ I don't see how this follows. Can you formalize your argument that it follows from the fact that "the proposals are coming from a density"?

Comment: @0xbadf00d first, I don't get pinged for comments unless you "@" me. Second, I think my indices are okay. You propose values for the next iteration of the chain, given the current state: "Given $X_{n-1}$, I sample $Y_n$ from $Q(X_{n-1}, \cdot)$ [sic]"

Comment: @0xbadf00d regarding the request for more formality, I can work on that

Comment: I cannot "@" you in a comment below a post of you. You should automatically get notified about any such comment. I'll check your edit soon.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I did that time... strange!

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Unfortunately, your argumentation is still too hand-wavy for me. I guess you're more kind of a practitioner, while I'm the theoretical guy. Please take note of my edit to the question. Maybe you can help me to finish things up.